# Detect text change in the corner of the video and get the timecode

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, video-processing

So I have a video with multiple scenes. each scene has a text in the bottom left/right of it (e.g. scene A with text "ABC", scene B with text "XYZ"...etc)

[image]

I want to detect when the scenes start and when it ends (in timecode if possible) to use ffmpeg to split the videos to multiple files.

I don't really care about extracting the text, just using it to know a start/end of a scene.

I tried to use [PySceneDetect](https://github.com/Breakthrough/PySceneDetect) with the "detect-content" algorithm, the results are good but still a lot of manual work that I have to do (maybe due to the nature of my videos)

To be specific, my question is, how can I use OpenCV (or any other tool you suggest) to read/report text change in the corner of video? or if you aware of a ready tool that will do the job?

Comment: We can not offer "any help" here. But you ask a **specific** question accompanied by your code.

Comment: Hi @KlausD., my question is how can I setup opencv to only focus on reading text from the bottom corner of the video, all the examples online show you how to ready "all" the text in the video

Comment: Then, show us what you have tried so far!

Comment: Is the camera fixed on a bracket or tripod, or is it hand-held and moving around?